# How do I detach the minecart with the rusted lever in Jumbleneck Mine?

Tags: west-of-loathing

On the first floor of jumbleneck mine, you can use the switch send the minecart into a back room to clear the path. In the back room, there is another minecart laden with dynamite and rocks that seems to be meant to go back into the first room to clear rubble and open the path forward.

Unfortunately the dynamite minecart is stuck to a rusted spring loaded mechanism. Interacting with it says that it will need "something heavier-duty than a can of oil".

How do I get this minecart unstuck and into the first room to clear the rubble?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the Jumbleneck Mine, next to the foreman's office, is a barrel of grease. Grab a bag of that and use that to oil the handle.